# R how to divide row corresponding to each factor level

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
  Date       location class  count
  <date>     <chr>    <fct>  <dbl>
1 2019-11-30 China    total   1000
2 2019-11-30 China    disney  1000
3 2019-11-30 China    marvel     5
4 2019-11-30 Vietnam  total     90
5 2019-11-30 Vietnam  disney    80
6 2019-11-30 Vietnam  marvel    10
```

Above is the head of my data, and I would like to divide count of china-marvel by china-total, and vietnam-marvel by vietnam-total and so on (assuming we only have date 2019-11-30)

After the calculation the output would look something like below:

```
Date        location     divided
2019-11-30  China        0.005
2019-11-30  Vietnam      0.111
```

It should be simple but really stuck. what is a good way to perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the mean of the indicator for `class == 'marvel'`, weighted by the counts

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[class != 'total', .(divided = weighted.mean(class == 'marvel', count)), 
   by = .(Date, location)]

#          Date location     divided
# 1: 2019-11-30    China 0.004975124
# 2: 2019-11-30  Vietnam 0.111111111
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
Date       location class  count
 2019-11-30 China    total   1000
 2019-11-30 China    disney  1000
 2019-11-30 China    marvel     5
 2019-11-30 Vietnam  total     90
 2019-11-30 Vietnam  disney    80
 2019-11-30 Vietnam  marvel    10
')
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I want 5/1000 for China and 10/90 for Vietnam.